# 'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, import

Brand new to python, I get "'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command" whenever I type import into the console.

Help?

Comment: I suspect that you are typing Python commands into a Windows shell prompt.

Comment: have you tried invoking the python interpreter first? run `python` from the console, then enter your `import` statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run python through the console, type 'python2' or 'python3' depending on which version you are using. You'll see a message saying what version you're on and then '>>>'. From there you can start typing 'import' and then the library name that you want to import, ex 'import random'. Have fun!